# Uniform convergence on $[0,+\infty[$ of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm e^{-nx}\sin (nx)}{\sqrt n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I'am looking to study the uniform convergence on $[0,+\infty[$ of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm e^{-nx}\sin (nx)}{\sqrt n}$$
The series  converges pointwise on $[0,+\infty[$, it also normally converges on $[a,+\infty[$,  $\forall$ a>0
But I don't see how to prove or refute the uniform convergence on  $[0,+\infty[$ , I tried with Abel's test for uniform convergence series without success:  difficulty  to prove  that $\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty} \mathrm e^{-nx}\sin (nx)$ is bounded uniformly in  $x\in [0,+\infty[$
Thank you in advance for help or answer

Comment: Have you tried Dirichlet's Test for Uniform Convergence ? (link: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence)

Comment: @  DecarbonatedOdes I don't know the Bose-Einstein distribution for the polylogarithm  @ Fei Cao I've already tried the Dirichlet's Test for Uniform Convergence @user284331 thank's for ur answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that it were, then
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\dfrac{e^{-kx}\sin(kx)}{\sqrt{k}}\right|<1
\end{align*}
for sufficiently large $n$ and $x\in[0,\infty)$.

Put $x=x_{n}=\pi/(4n)$ then $\sin(kx_{n})\geq 1/\sqrt{2}$ for all $n\leq k\leq 2n$, and hence
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\dfrac{e^{-kx_{n}}\sin(kx_{n})}{\sqrt{k}}\right|&=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\dfrac{e^{-kx_{n}}\sin(kx_{n})}{\sqrt{k}}\\
&\geq\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\dfrac{e^{-2n\cdot\pi/(4n)}}{\sqrt{k}}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{-\pi/2}}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}.
\end{align*}
Now we see that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\approx\int_{n}^{2n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx\approx\sqrt{n}\rightarrow\infty
\end{align*}
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.